# Correct way of randomly selecting token Ids from already minted NFT's

Tags: solidity, remix, tokens, nft, smart-contract-wallets

I have an NFT project with **1000 NFTs**. As part of my project, users who hold an NFT will be entered into a lottery.

The function I want to implement is the following:

Select x number of users to participate in the lottery. So lets say **500 NFTs** have been minted out of the **1000 NFTs**, I want the **500 users** to participate in the lottery, and I get to pick any number of winners.
In short, 500 NFT holders are entered into a draw, and 10 NFTs are randomly selected as winners.

I was fortunate enough to find a smart contract that match my criteria.

In the below code, the `selectWinners()` functions accepts a uint256 noOfWinners as a parameter, which then creates a date for a future draw, and increments a draw by 1.

The `selectAWinner()` function is looped x number of times (x = noOfWinners), and selects random winners.

The `rand()` function accepts random address and a random number. I believe this function helps in finding random winners.

In the below code, the `selectAWinner()` function generates a random token id between 1 to 5000, because the maxSupply of that project is 5000.

What I want is for the function to generate random token id's between 1 to 500, because 500 NFTs have been minting out of the 1000.

> What I've tried:

In the `rand()` function, I tried to use `totalSupply` (the amount of NFT minted i.e. 500) instead of `maxSupply`. Unfortunately, I'm encountering errors.

Where am I going wrong? Any help is very much appreciated!

```
 function selectWinners(uint256 noOfWinners) public onlyOwner {
    require(!paused, "ERROR: Contract is paused");
    require(lotteryActive, "ERROR: Lottery not active yet");
    require(noOfWinners <= 50, "ERROR: Too many winners selected");

    uint256 epochNow = block.timestamp;
    uint256 nextLotteryDate = lotteryDates[lotteryDates.length - 1];

    require(epochNow >= nextLotteryDate, "ERROR: Cannot draw yet, too early");

    for (uint256 i = 0; i < noOfWinners; i++) {
        selectAWinner(
            0,
            epochNow,
            msg.sender,
            nextLotteryDate,
            msg.sender,
            0
        );
    }

    lotteryDates.push(epochNow + (epochDay * lotteryIntervalDays));

    // increment draw
    drawNumber++;
}


function selectAWinner(
    uint256 it,
    uint256 epochNow,
    address sender,
    uint256 lotteryDate,
    address randomAddr,
    uint256 randomNo
) internal {
    // Generate random id between 1 - 5000 (corresponds to NFT id)

    uint256 winningToken = rand(randomAddr, randomNo);
    address winnerAddress = ERC721.ownerOf(winningToken);
    uint256 lastWon = _winners[winnerAddress];

    bool alreadyWon = (lastWon == lotteryDate);

    Winner memory win;

    if ((it < 5) && alreadyWon) {
        uint256 newIt = it + 1;
        return
            selectAWinner(
                newIt,
                epochNow,
                sender,
                lotteryDate,
                winnerAddress,
                winningToken
            );
    } else if ((it >= 5) && alreadyWon) {
        return;
    } else {
        win.date = lotteryDate;
        win.winner = winnerAddress;
        win.tokenId = winningToken;
        winnerLog[drawNumber].push(win);

        _winners[winnerAddress] = lotteryDate;
    }

    return;
}

function rand(address randomAddress, uint256 randomNo) internal view returns (uint256) {
    uint256 seed = uint256(
        keccak256(
            abi.encodePacked(
                (block.timestamp - randomNo) +
                    block.difficulty +
                    ((
                        uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.coinbase)))
                    ) / (block.timestamp)) +
                    block.gaslimit +
                    ((uint256(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(randomAddress)))) /
                        (block.timestamp)) +
                    block.number
            )
        )
    );

    return (seed - ((seed / maxSupply) * maxSupply)) + 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you share what errors you are encountering?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clear. The issue with the code when I changed the return for the rand() function to => "return ((seed - ((seed / totalSupply) * totalSupply)) + 1);" is that it returns only 1 winner instead of a specified amount of winners. So if I enter 10 winners in the selectWinners() function, it only returns 1 winner.

Comment: I think the the line `(seed - ((seed / maxSupply) * maxSupply)) + 1` will always give 1 as the output, as `maxSupply` cancels out and then `seed` cancels out. If you want a number below `maxSupply` or `totalSupply`, you could do modulus on it. It'll look like `return seed%totalSupply`.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you so much for your explanation. So you're saying that all I need to do to product random number between 1 and 500 is place a modulus operator right after the seed? So: "return seed % totalSupply" ?

Comment: Yup, that shoud do the trick

Comment: I really do appreciate your help! Thank you sooo much

Comment: Will this ever return a 0? if so, do I need to write it like this => "return seed % totalSupply + 1" ?

Comment: Yeah, it might return zero. You could return `(seed % totalSupply) + 1`. Now its range will be from 1 to totalSupply.